# Can't Remove leafgarland-vim TypeScript experimentalDecorator warning

Tags: vim, plugins, typescript, tsc

I have the **[leafgarland-vim](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim)** plugin installed, and when I save my *.ts* file, I always get this warning:

[image: Screenshot of the warning inside VIM]

I've tried adding `let g:typescript_compiler_options="--experimentalDecorators"` to my *~/.vimrc*, and I've also entered that command from inside vim, after first typing ":". I can even do `:echo g:typescript_compiler_options` and it returns `--experimentalDecorators`. Yet every time I go to save I get this error.

How can I get this error to go away? `--experimentalDecorators` just doesn't seem to do its job.

**edit:**
I tried this from inside vim:
*:let g:typescript_compiler_options = '--dnwejuidbnwejudbn'*
And the code still compiled, with the same warning. I don't think the *let g:typescript_compiler_options* is actually doing anything.

**edit2:**
[image: Apparently none of these settings actually do anything]

**edit3:**
In the meantime, this hack gets rid of the warning:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing but I think you are seeing these warnings from another plugin, probably Syntastic. Syntastic uses its own compiler settings.

You could try adding something like this line to your vimrc:

`let g:syntastic_typescript_tsc_args = "--experimentalDecorators"`

See `:help syntastic-checker-options` for more details.